# App.jsx:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'TodoComponent' of undefined

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, import, compilation

I try to style some reactjs component. 
My browser development console return me this error :

> App.jsx:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'TodoComponent' of
>   undefined
>       at App.render (App.jsx:11)

I have try to import with the following syntaxes :

App.jsx :

```
import {styles} from ...
import {styles as styles} from...
```

styles.js  :

```
export default styles... 
export styles...
```

All failling.

Here my tree structure :

```
src content directory - ls :
App.jsx  styles.js
```

here my App.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
// Import the styles
import {styles} from "./styles.js";


class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
    <div style={styles.TodoComponent}>
(...)
```

here my style.js :

```
    var TodoComponent = {
      width: "300px",
      margin: "30px auto",
      backgroundColor: "#44014C",
      minHeight: "200px",
      boxSizing: "border-box"
    };

    var styles = {


    TodoComponent: TodoComponent,
( other styles...) 
    };
```

Here my webpack.config.js :

```
var webpack = require("webpack") ;
var path = require("path") ;
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
module.exports= {
mode: "development",
devtool : "source-map",
context : __dirname + "/src",
entry : { app : __dirname + "/src/App.jsx" },
output : { path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public/"),
          filename : "frontend.bundle.js"
},
module: {
   rules: [ {
     test: /\.js|jsx$/,
     exclude: /node_modules/,
   include: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
     use: [
       {
   loader: 'babel-loader',
   options: {
     presets: ["es2015", "stage-1", "react"]
   }
       }
     ]
   },
 {
 test: /\.css$/,
 use: [
   { loader: 'style-loader' },
   {
     loader: 'css-loader',
     options: {
       modules: true
     }
 }
 ]}
]},


optimization : {

 splitChunks: {
     chunks: "async",
     minSize: 3000,
     minChunks: 1,
     maxAsyncRequests: 5,
     maxInitialRequests: 3,
     automaticNameDelimiter: "~",
     name: true,
     cacheGroups: {
   vendors: {
       test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
       priority: -10
   },
     default: {
       minChunks: 2,
       priority: -20,
       reuseExistingChunk: true
   }
     }
 }
},
devServer: {
  proxy: {
  "/api": "http://localhost:7000"
},
 contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, "public/"),
 open : true
}
};
```

config.babelrc :

```
{
  "presets": ["env", "react", "stage-0"]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to export it:

```
var TodoComponent = { width: "300px", margin: "30px auto", backgroundColor: "#44014C", minHeight: "200px", boxSizing: "border-box" };

export const styles = { TodoComponent: TodoComponent, };
```

Comment: Thank you Tomasz it works =). Do you have an advice to make "export default style" ? I oar  on it since a while and it still challenges me